# Not able to convert existing WSL1 distro to WSL2

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have installed Ubuntu-18.04 on my Windows 10 (Build 19041 which meets the requirements for WSL2) and am trying to convert this distro into WSL2. I have been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) guide.

To do so, I run the following command in Windows PowerShell:

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 2
```

But I get the following error after a few minutes:

```
This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
```

I have tried different networks (fearing it was a firewall issue) but to no avail. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you fixed this?

Answer (score -1):

[Make sure you have the linux kernel update package installed.](https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel) Then, run `wsl --set-default-version 2` to set the default WSL version to WSL2.

Comment: I did that. I still get the same error. However, after running  `wsl --set-default-version 1`, I am able to install Ubuntu 18.04. Something to do with WSL2.